# Cake 3: column of type JSON stores a NULL as string "null"

Tags: mysql, json, cakephp, cakephp-3.3

My model is defined as follows:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Database\Schema\Table as Schema;

class AppLogsTable extends Table
{    
    protected function _initializeSchema(Schema $schema) {
        $schema->columnType('data', 'json');
        return $schema;
    }       
}
```

The JSON format is correctly applied when saving into database and when retrieving data. However, if I set `$appLog->data = null` and save it through `$this->appLogs->save($appLog)` it would save a string `null` into the database rather than a real *NULL* value. The colum `data` in the `app_logs` table is set to accept nulls.

If I uncomment the column type definition, it stores nulls correctly.

**How to keep the automatic JSON data type and store *NULL* correctly from the model?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use a custom/extended database type class that handles `null` values accordingly, the built-in one will pass everything through `json_encode()` no matter what.

Something along the lines of this:

```php
// src/Database/Type/NullAwareJsonType.php

namespace App\Database\Type;

use Cake\Database\Driver;
use Cake\Database\Type\JsonType;

class NullAwareJsonType extends JsonType
{
    public function toDatabase($value, Driver $driver)
    {
        if ($value === null) {
            return null;
        }

        return parent::toDatabase($value, $driver);
    }
}
```

You can then either override the built in `json` type:

```php
// config/bootstrap.php

\Cake\Database\Type::map('json', \App\Database\Type\NullAwareJsonType::class);
```

or map it as a new type and set the column type accordingly:

```php
\Cake\Database\Type::map('nullAwareJson', \App\Database\Type\NullAwareJsonType::class);
```

```php
$schema->columnType('data', 'nullAwareJson');
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Database Basics > Adding Custom Types](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types)**

Comment: After seeing this (and experiencing this myself a few times) I think it might be time to pluginize this: See [Shim plugin PR](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-shim/pull/10).